# Best way to get variable from another script

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 2D game and I have many c# script. Some variable like `Speed` influence to a lot of gameObject's and script. I want to all of these script's read `Speed` variable from just one script and I do this with property and it worked very well.

But my problem is I want when I change the `Speed` from that script, Other script detect this change and change their own `Speed` variable. Currently it's not like this because those script read `Speed` in `Start()` method.

That variable may change five time's in all the game duration so I did not want look for change every frame, Just when it changed, Something magically tell that script's too update the value!

I have some idea to solve this problem but I think these are not good:

- Get variable from that component in `Update()` or `FixedUpdate()` method (I think it's bad because every frame this code runs)
- In that public script I create a list of script's that use `Speed` variable and when `Speed` changed, send a message to those script's.
- And I have a lot of other idea that I know it's wrong so I don't write that.

Update:
This is my public class that contain `Speed` variable:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Utility : MonoBehaviour {

    public float _Speed = 2f;
    public float Speed
    {
        get{return _Speed;}
        set{_Speed = value;}
    }

    void Start () {
    }


    void Update () {
        //Here I can detect change of this variable and send message to other scripts
    }
}
```

And other script access to that variable like this( Just example):

```
void Start () {
        float mySpeed = GetComponent<Utility> ().Speed;
}
void Update () {
    // Or here I can read speed every frame like below:
    // mySpeed = GetComponent<Utility> ().Speed;
}
```

And in this project those other script's need the value of "Speed" in any frame, Not just in some situation

Comment: You should show us your "ideas that you think are not good." This isn't a code writing service, please show us what you have tried, and we will help you get started.

Comment: You should provide some code to help illustrate your problem.  It shounds like you are using a static class and changing that classes Speed property causes other things to change, which is not desired.

Comment: Wait a second, I will update my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not have multiple speed variables, just have one, and call for it every time you need to get it

```
SpeedHolder speedHolder;

public void Update()
{
    transform.position += speedHolder.Speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

If you *REALLY* want this done another way... you can use events and delegates.

```
public class SpeedHolder
{
    private float _speed;

    public event Action<float> OnSpeedChange;

    public float Speed
    {
        get { return _speed; }
        set { SetSpeed(value); }
    }

    public SetSpeed(float value)
    {
        _speed = value;
        if(OnSpeedChange != null)
            OnSpeedChange(_speed);
    }
}
```

now in every start method of every script which uses a speed float variable, you need to add this line: `SpeedHolder.OnSpeedChange += ChangeSpeed;` and have a method like this one:

```
public void ChangeSpeed(value)
{
    speed = value;
}
```

Comment: Yes I know that but I don't know how?!!! And in this project those other script's need the value of "Speed" in any frame, not just in some situation

Comment: But you were saying you didnt want to do it this way.. implying you knew the idea of it already

Comment: "I have some idea to solve this problem but I think these are not good:

1: Get variable from that component in Update() or FixedUpdate() method (I think it's bad because every frame this code runs)"  <-- this idea is in fact good you should do this

Comment: I mean that variable may change five time's in all the game duration so I did not want look for change every frame, Just when it changed, Something magically say that script's too update the value!

Comment: Its not a heavy call to ask for a variable, especially when you already have the other script cached. Do it, its fine i promise. If you really don't want to do it this way, your going to be getting into events and adding tons of lines of code you don't need for no reason.

Comment: Tnx for your help, But for now I just not mark your post as answer because maybe someone have another idea. tnx again.

Comment: Okay i gave you another way of doing it, but like i said, you can avoid tons of unnecessary code. But this would be your best alternative i guarantee it